# Ayuda ¿Como llenar un dataSet en javascript?

Tags: javascript, array, datatable, dataset, tabla-dinámica

tengo la siguiente linea de codigo

```
var registro1 = [ "1", "Perez", "Lopez", "Luis", "Martin", "22" ];
var registro2 = [ "2", "Gonzales", "Jimenez", "Reyna", "Maria", "18" ];
var registro2 = [ "3", "Rodriguez", "Dominguez", "Luis", "Fernando", "23" ];
var registro2 = [ "4", "Martinez", "Montero", "Fernanda", "Manuela", "18" ];


var tabla = [registro1,registro2,registro3,registro4];
```

¿Como puedo llenar la tabla de manera dinámica sin tener que usar tantas variables?

Comment: Todas tus variables tiene en común registro. Se diferencian en el sufijo. Itera agregándolo usa un `ciclo for`. De paso, Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. Has el [tour] para enterarte acerca de cómo funcionamos y lee la página [ask] para organizar tus preguntas de modo que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y te brinden las respuestas que necesitas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no quieres declarar tantas variables:

```
var tabla = [
    [ "1", "Perez", "Lopez", "Luis", "Martin", "22" ],
    [ "2", "Gonzales", "Jimenez", "Reyna", "Maria", "18" ],
    [ "3", "Rodriguez", "Dominguez", "Luis", "Fernando", "23" ],
    [ "4", "Martinez", "Montero", "Fernanda", "Manuela", "18" ]
];
```

O en manera más dinámica:

```
// declaración de la variable tabla
var tabla = [];
// loop
do {
    // llena un nuevo registro de cualquier manera
    var nuevo_registro = [ "X", "Xxxx", "Xxxx", "Xxxx", "Xxxxx", "XX" ];
    // llena la tabla con el nuevo registro
    tabla.push(nuevo_registro);
// condición para terminar de llenar la tabla
} while (fin == 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

De esto

```
var registro1 = [ "1", "Perez", "Lopez", "Luis", "Martin", "22" ];
var registro2 = [ "2", "Gonzales", "Jimenez", "Reyna", "Maria", "18" ];
var registro2 = [ "3", "Rodriguez", "Dominguez", "Luis", "Fernando", "23" ];
var registro2 = [ "4", "Martinez", "Montero", "Fernanda", "Manuela", "18" ];


var tabla = [registro1,registro2,registro3,registro4];
```

Se puede pasar a esto:

```
var tabla = [
     [ "1", "Perez", "Lopez", "Luis", "Martin", "22" ],
     [ "2", "Gonzales", "Jimenez", "Reyna", "Maria", "18" ],
     [ "3", "Rodriguez", "Dominguez", "Luis", "Fernando", "23" ],
     [ "4", "Martinez", "Montero", "Fernanda", "Manuela", "18" ]
];
```

Metiendo todos esos arrays en un solo array global.